# Insert string in parentheses of a column at the beginning of a string of another column python

Tags: python, insert, cpu-word, parentheses

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below :

```
Name    Country         (Title)
0  Elizabeth    England      (Queen of)
1    Jackson        Pop       (King of)
2      Trump        USA  (President of)
3     Macron     France  (President of)
4    Clinton        USA            None
5      Blair    England            None
6      Elvis  RocknRoll       (King of)
```

What I would like to get is the following:

```
 Name             Country                (Title)
0  Elizabeth       Queen of England      (Queen of)
1    Jackson       King of Pop           (King of)
2      Trump       President of USA      (President of)
3     Macron       President of France   (President of)
4    Clinton       USA                   None
5      Blair       England               None
6      Elvis       King of RocknRoll     (King of)
```

I have made several attempts (including with regular expressions). I have tried the code below which is pretty clear but does not function either.

Any suggestion would be welcome !

Thanks.

```
def extract(w):
    begin = w.find('(')
    if begin == -1:
        return ''
    begin += 1 
    end = w.find(')', begin)
    if end == -1: 
        return w[begin:]
    else:
        return w[begin:end]
for i in range(len(table)):
    if table['(Title)'][i] != None :
        table['Country'][i] = extract(table['Title'[i]).str.cat(table['Country'].values.astype(str), sep='')
```

```
 Name             Country                (Title)
0  Elizabeth       Queen of England      (Queen of)
1    Jackson       King of Pop           (King of)
2      Trump       President of USA      (President of)
3     Macron       President of France   (President of)
4    Clinton       USA                   None
5      Blair       England               None
6      Elvis       King of RocknRoll     (King of)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:-

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    concat_string = row.Title.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')+' '+ row.Country if row.Title else row.Country

    df.at[idx, 'Country'] = concat_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['new_country'] = df['(title)'].str[1:-1] + ' ' + df['country']
df.loc[pd.notna(df['(title)']), 'country'] = df['new_country']
```

Comment: Thanks Aryerez. Your code deles the first and last strings even when they’re not parentheses. I will try to fix that.

Comment: Here is the code I found : for i in range(len(table)):
    if table['Title'][i] != None :
        if table['Title'][i].startswith('('):
            table['New'][i] = table['Title'][i][1:-1] + ' ' + table['Country'][i]
        else :
            table['New'][i] = table['Title'][i] + ' ' + table['Country'][i]
    else :
        table['New'][i] = None
table

Comment: @levesxv Looping over rows in pandas dataframe is very inefficient. In this case it seems that his data is organized with parentheses, so it was a suitable solution. In other cases a good solution is `df['(title)'].str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')`, but probably using regex would be smarter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The dataset includes data with and data without parentheses (as in my example). The last piece of code you suggested is indeed better. I am not completely comfortable (and familiar) with regular expression. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks !